скрипт на python для телеграмм, библиотека telethon, при запуске с помощью cron или .service требует авторизацию
Собственно, основная суть в теме.
Есть скрипт на python для телеграмм, используется библиотека telethon, при запуске с помощью cron или .service повторно требует авторизацию.
Файл .session на месте, при запуске скрипта из терминала или обращении к скрипту через браузер - скрипт выполняется без проблем, а при запуске его по расписанию с помощью cron или через службу .service (через задание периодичности запуска с помощью .timer ) - скрипт падает , т.к. заново запрашивается номер телефона (это видно в syslog). Возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с таким? Как возможно исправить? Чтобы и не из терминала/браузера скрипт запускался без запроса авторизации. Гугление пока результатов не приносит(


Убедитесь, что файл .session имеет правильные права доступа и принадлежит пользователю, под которым запускается скрипт
Добавьте логирование в скрипт, чтобы понять, на каком этапе происходит сбой

